# Find and Replace value in Javascript object

Tags: javascript, jquery, replace

I have following javascript object. On this object I want to perform find and replace operation. I want to replace values only for second column. I want to replace 'total' with `XXXX` and 'data' with `DDDD` . What is the most efficient way to perform this operation.

```
{
    "Result": [
        [
            "1",
            "Total",
            "Franchise",
            "5,491,396,782",
            "2,691,451,027"
        ],
        [
            "2",
            "Total",
            "Growth",
            "68,727,420",
            "45,152,969"
        ],
        [
            "3",
            "Total",
            "Research",
            "3,970,296,773",
            "1,921,277,988"
        ],
        [
            "4",
            "Data",
            "Franchise",
            "4,793,487,319",
            "2,347,241,939"
        ],
        [
            "5",
            "Data",
            "Growth",
            "65,353,557",
            "40,817,844"
        ],
        [
            "6",
            "Data",
            "Research",
            "3,411,890,959",
            "1,644,610,206"
        ]
    ]
}
```

Thank you

Comment: Look at `underscore.js` lib. It has a lot of methods for collections.

Comment: Loop over your structure, replace stuff you are looking for with proper new values. As @YD1m mentioned, that would be pretty quick with Underscore.

Answer (score 1):

```
for(var i=0; i<result.length; i++)
    if(result[i].length >= 2)
        result[i][1] = result[i][1].replace(/^Total$/, "xxxx").replace(/^Data$/, "DDDD");
```

Answer (score 0):

iteration, iteration, iteration

```
for (key in obj) {
    for (var i=0; i<obj[key].length; i++) {
        for (var j=0; j<obj[key][i].length; j++) {
            if (obj[key][i][j] == 'Total') obj[key][i][j] = 'XXXX';
            if (obj[key][i][j] == 'Data') obj[key][i][j] = 'DDDD';
        }
    }
}
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/bjuvj/)

Comment: Thank you for quick reply. What value u will store in key in this case?

Comment: You don't have to worry about key, it's a reference to the current key inside the loop, so it pretty much sets itself.